# Get the size (size in Kb or MB) of an featured image?

Tags: attachments, images, featured-post

I need to display some featured image info on post page. Among other info I need to display file size of image (featured image of post).

I tried this function inside single.php.

```
<?php
function getSize($file){
   $bytes = filesize($file);
   $s = array('b', 'Kb', 'Mb', 'Gb');
   $e = floor(log($bytes)/log(1024));

  return sprintf('%.2f '.$s[$e], ($bytes/pow(1024, floor($e))));
}
?>
```

and to echo that:

```
<?php echo getSize('/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/some-file-name.jpg'); ?>
```

It works, but I need help to make ti automatically grab featured image url, not to manually enter it in code?

For example I use this to echo featured image ("full") url:

```
 <?php
 if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
   $full_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full');
echo $thumb_image_url[0];
 }
?>
```

Could you please help to combine it, or to provide me with another solution?

Comment: If the answer was helpful to you, then consider accepting it. See »[What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)« and/or »[Why is voting important?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)«, more information about the WordPress Development model is available at the [help].

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`get_attached_file()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_attached_file) to:

> Retrieve attached file path based on attachment ID.

And [`get_post_thumbnail_id()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_thumbnail_id) to determine the post thumbnail of the current post, or any post if you set the `$post_id` parameter. Exemplary usage:

```
$bytes = filesize(
    get_attached_file(
        get_post_thumbnail_id()
    )
);
```

Use [`size_format()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/size_format) to

> Convert a given number of bytes into a human readable format

```
$hr_size = size_format( $bytes );
```

If you are actually want to get the size of one of the intermediate sizes, the above shows the file size of the full image, make use of [`image_get_intermediate_size()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/image_get_intermediate_size), where:

> The metadata 'sizes' is used for compatible sizes that can be used for the parameter $size value.

Which means it uses [`wp_get_attachment_metadata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_metadata) to get the data. In addition you need [`wp_upload_dir()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_dir) to construct the path. Exemplary usage:

```
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
$metadata_size = image_get_intermediate_size( 
    get_post_thumbnail_id(),
    'thumbnail'
);
$path_inter = $upload_dir[ 'basedir' ] . '/' . $metadata_size[ 'path' ];
$bytes = filesize(
    $path_inter
);
$hr_size = size_format( $bytes );
```

Comment: I am new to WP. Could you please paste for me exactly what I should put inside single.php to show file size of featured image? For, at least 'full" image size, "medum" image size would be great too?

Comment: @user1038179 All you need is outlined in my answer. You really pretty much just have to use it, read the documentation I linked for each functionality. The last code block should definitely get you there. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. Still, it is difficult for me to understand which of php codes, with or without any modification, in which order to paste in my single.php? I tried many times, but, I get nothing.