# Show Featured Image Dimensions and size frontend with shortcode

Tags: php, shortcode

I was wondering if I can show my featured image Dimensions (W x H in px) and the filesize in mb. In my Wordpress post with a shortcode.

thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible. Building upon the answer Nicolai Grossherr gave to [Get the size (size in Kb or MB) of an featured image?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/152217/get-the-size-size-in-kb-or-mb-of-an-featured-image) you could do something like this,

```
// e.g. in functions.php
add_shortcode( 'my_image_metadata', 'my_image_metadata_callback' );
function my_image_metadata_callback($atts) {
  $img_meta = wp_get_attachment_metadata( get_post_thumbnail_id() );
  if ( ! $img_meta ) {
    return;
  }

  $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
  $bytes = filesize(
    $upload_dir[ 'basedir' ] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $img_meta[ 'file' ]
  );
  if ( ! $bytes ) {
    return;
  }

  $file_size = size_format( $bytes );

  return sprintf(
    '<span>
      <span class="dimensions">%d x %d px</span>
      <span class="filesize">%s</span>
    </span>',
    $img_meta['width'],
    $img_meta['height'],
    $file_size ?: ''
  );
}
```

Comment: You are Amazing! Thank you very much, it worked exactly as I wished :)

Comment: @timothyhoenson, I'm glad to hear that. Please consider marking the answer as accepted so that the community will know that this question has been resolved. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers